# How to remove extra character while redirection using Rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am facing one issue while redirection. you can treat my site as example.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/departures www.example.com/styles/412007AP0BT5874?utm_source=departures&utm_medium=display_premium&utm_campaign=print
```

But it redirect to `www.example.com/styles/412007AP0BT5874?utm_source=departures&utm_medium=display_premium&utm_campaign=print#412007AP0BT5874`

Extra `#412007AP0BT5874` is coming as per site functionality i.e. if any more character is appended after `www.example.com/styles/412007AP0BT5874` then style number is appended with #.

I want to know if there is any way to remove extra character through redirection?

Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your original URL also contains a departure number in the format `example.com/departure#412007AP0BT5874` and is being replaced at the end based on your rewrite rule. The following change will match your URL with the departure number.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^departures#(.*)$ www.example.com/styles/$1?utm_source=departures&utm_medium=display_premium&utm_campaign=print
```

Also, I assume above that the original URL ends with the departure number `#412007AP0BT5874` hence the `$` at the end. If it is followed by something else, the pattern needs to reflect that.

Comment: Actually i want to redirect `www.example.com/departures` to `www.example.com/styles/412007AP0BT5874?utm_source=departures&utm_medium=display_premium&utm_campaign=print`

Comment: This seems to do the job in that case: `RewriteRule ^departures www.example.com/styles/412007AP0BT5874?utm_source=departures&utm_medium=display_premium&utm_campaign=print [L]`. This will ensure no other rules defined afterwards apply to it.

Comment: Thanks Bipul but it still didn't resolve my issue but now i find that appended things is done by the code not by Apache, so it will not work. However this is now again a new learning of Keeping [L] if we want further avoid the apache rule. Thanks.